# After installing ubuntu server error PXE-E53 and PXE-M0F - Fujitsu Primergy S1

Tags: boot, server, system-installation, pxe

My server was running on *Debian 11*. I have wanted to reinstall it with a new Debian version and after installation, it wrote me:

```
Please remove installation medium, then press Enter
```

I have removed the disk and pressed Enter. Then it wrote:

```
CLIENT MAC ADDR: ... GUID: ...
PXE-E53: No boot file name received
PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel Boot Agent.
Operating System not found
```

I have found on the internet that there is a problem with disks, but right after the installation?
I can see both of my disks in the *BIOS* - HDD 500GB and SSD 120GB.
Also, *BIOS* is telling me their *"OK"* state.

I tried to install *Ubuntu - ubuntu-22.04.1-live-server-amd64* server to check if there is just some error with *ISO* file from *Debian* but there I am with the same error again.

I am Booting it with USB 16GB

Intel Boot Agent GE v1.3.27

CPU: Intel Xeon X3350 @ 2.83GHz

RAM: 4x 2048MB DDR2-800 ECC Hynix S6

GPU: No graphic card

---

**Edit 1**

When booting Linux installation and continuing with just a console, I can see my disks with their size. Also, the OS is able to install itself on those disks but cannot just boot. Displays that error above.
I also tried Windows Server 2008 and it **CANNOT** find disks. Maybe some installation broke drivers?

Comment: Please provide your OS/release details; you primarily mention off-topic Debian.  You do mention Ubuntu Server, but without details so we cannot know which server product, which release and thus which installer (default or alternate) you're asking about. Choices exist for Ubuntu to aid with some hardware setups.

Comment: Okay, it is updated. The OS is ubuntu-22.04.1-live-server-amd64